# Nginx vhost cache symlink

Tags: caching, nginx, deployment, capistrano

I've got a problem with deploying my application. I have a PHP application and I deploy my application with Capistrano to my server.

Capistrano makes a new release folder with the latest version of my application and my current folder symlinks to the that release. That works fine, it really links the latest release.

But when I go the the URL of my website nothing changes, the files are from the old release folder even when the symlink links to the current folder (latest release).

Does Nginx cache all my files? Or does it cache my symlinks, I have no idea.

**Folder structure:**

```
 current (symlink new release)
 releases
     new release
     old release
```

**Vhost:**

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name servname.com;
    root /apps/application/production/current/public; 
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, also trying to find a solution. The workaround I found was that if you create and delete a file in the nginx folder, it will force nginx to point to the new symlink, but I don't like this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is at real path cache level. It caches the PHP file with the symlink path. What you need to do is provide the real document path.

You need to add these 2 lines in your config file

```
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

The important part is `$realpath_root`.

From the documentation:

```
$realpath_root
an absolute pathname corresponding to the root or alias directive’s value for the current request, with all symbolic links resolved to real paths
```

Meaning `$realpath_root` solves all symlinks to their real path. This is the important part.

So your `location ~ \.php$` would become

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Make sure the `include fastcgi_params` if present does not overwrite the 2 directives you just added.

Comment: For the record, while the solution is correct, the issue here was not the opcode cache, but the [realpath cache](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-size).

Comment: I've updated my response and removed the Opcache reference.

Comment: @DanielLucaCleanUnicorn Can you explain what is difference between $document_root and $realpath_root? I set 
 $docuement_root before and it doesn't work but your solution works for me.

Comment: I added a comment about realpath_root in my answer. It solves all symbolic links to their real path.